# Como recarregar data depois de uma ação VueJS

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

Minha lista permanece a mesma depois de excluir um item, só atualiza quando aperto <kbd>F5</kbd> na tela. Já tentei utilizar `componentKey`, mas só funciona quando dou 2 cliques.

Segue código atual do componente:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Raça</td>
        <td>#</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="d in dog.data" :key="d.id">
        <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.titulo }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.conteudo }}</td>
        <td><button @click="deleteDog(d.id)">Deletar</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import api from "../services/api";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dog: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    api.get("dogs").then((response) => (this.dog = response.data));
  },
  methods: {
    deleteDog(id) {
      api.delete("dog/" + id);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode remover o elemento da lista `dog` após fazer a chamada da API, usando simples métodos de array.

Dentro do método `deleteDog`:

```js
deleteDog(id) {
  api.delete("dog/" + id).then(() => {
     // localiza o indice do elemento no array
     const index = this.dog.findIndex(dog => dog.id === id)  

     if (index >= 0) {
        // remove apenas ele do array
        this.dog.splice(index, 1) 
     }
  });
}
```

Ou, chamar a API novamente, que irá trazer os dados atualizados. Pode não ser muito elegante fazer uma chamada toda vez que excluir um elemento, mas pode ser feito:

```js
deleteDog(id) {
  api.delete("dog/" + id).then(() => {
     // chama novamente a API com os dados atualizados
     api.get("dogs").then((response) => (this.dog = response.data));
  });
},
```

Como o Vue trabalha com o conceito de View em função do estado, alterar o valor de `dog` vai ocasionar o *refresh* somente do componente que tem esse estado, sem precisar apertar <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A sua array está sendo populada no momento em que a view é montada, então qualquer alteração na api que ocorra depois disso não vai ser refletida na sua array de resultados. Para que as alterações no view ocorram, você deve atualizar (excluir o item em específico) a sua array toda vez que o método deleteDog for acionado.

Vue é reativo, então se você modificar a array, ele vai recarregar o elemento automaticamente, o problema é que esse o método deleteDog atualiza apenas a fonte de dados.

Existem meios de essas atualizações serem feitas automaticamente, a depender do framework ou pacotes que você utiliza. O Meteor, por exemplo, mantém uma cópia do banco de dados no navegador, que fica sincronizada com o banco original, então todas as alterações são refletidas na view para todo mundo que está vendo, mas você pesquisar mais sobre isso depois.