# Erro vuejs 'this.$delete is not a function'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Eu já tenho uma teoria do que pode ser esse erro, tenho feito um curso em Vue2 mas estou com o Vue3 num dado momento o curso passa duas funções de finalizar a tarefa e de apagar a mesma:

Adcionar:

```
toggleTodo(todo) {
      const index = this.todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todo.id);
      if (index > -1) {
        const checked = !this.todos[index].checked;
        this.$set(this.todos, index, { ...this.todos[index], checked });
      }
},
```

Apagar:

```
removeTodo(todo) {
      const index = this.todos.findIndex((item) => item.id === todo.id);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.$delete(this.todos, index)
      }
    },
```

Mas para as duas tenho um retorno: `this.$set is not a function` e `this.$delete is not a function`, mas não consigo achar como resolve-los. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: SS no $set eu tento entrar com uma nova tarefa e no $delete eu tento apagar ele do array.

Comment: Porque não fazer `this.todos.splice(index, 1);`?

Comment: [Aqui](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) diz que seria `Vue.delete(..)` e raramente deve ser usado. O mesmo vale para o `$set`, creio eu. Então, porque não trabalha diretamente com esse estado usando somente métodos de array?

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em uma pergunta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459010/vuejs-remove-element-from-lists), foi dito que se usar o gerenciador de estado Vuex, os métodos `$delete` e ,provavelmente, o `$set` não devem estar diponíveis, oque pode explicar a mensagem de erro `this.$delete is not a function`.

O indicado seria usar `Vue.delete`, mas dee acordo com a documentação, este deve ser usado raramente deve ser usado:

> Delete a property on an object. If the object is reactive, ensure the
> deletion triggers view updates. This is primarily used to get around
> the limitation that Vue cannot detect property deletions, but you
> should rarely need to use it.

Neste caso, como seu estado é um array `this.todos`, alterar este objeto usando simples métodos de array, irá ser o suficiente.

#### Finalizar uma tarefa

Que tal usar o `map`?:

```
toggleTodo(todo) {
  this.todos = this.todos.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === todo.id) {
      item.checked = !item.checked // inverte o estado do 'checked'
    }

    return item
  });
},
```

Veja um exemplo para entender a lógica:

```js
var persons = [
  { id: 1, checked: false },
  { id: 2, checked: false },
  { id: 3, checked: false }
];

persons = persons.map(item => {
 if (item.id === 3) item.checked = true
 
 return item
})

console.log(persons)
```

#### Remover uma tarefa

Que tal o `splice`?:

```
removeTodo(todo) {
  const index = this.todos.findIndex((item) => item.id === todo.id);

  if (index > -1) {
   this.todos.splice(index, 1); // não precisa reatribuir ao this.todos 
  }                             // pois 'splice' já altera o array original
},
```

Veja um exemplo para entender a lógica:

```js
var persons = [{
    id: 1,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    checked: false
  }
];

const index = persons.findIndex((item) => item.id === 3);

if (index > -1) {
  persons.splice(index, 1); 
}

console.log(persons) // removeu o item de id 3
```

Como o Vue trabalha com o conceito de View em função do estado (como já mencionei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/508009/95771)), alterar o valor de `this.todos` vai ocasionar uma atualização da view.